# JQuery Novice To Ninja

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know were to get the source code sample files for the book Jquery Novice to Ninja

Answer (score 3):

If you **Google it**, the first URL is to sitepoint (the makers of that book)

Book: http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/

at the end of the page you have "more Info"

where you can get not only the all [code](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/code.php?SID=363b4ae08a2b50445dcac449be2e5ff8) but also the [errata](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/errata.php)

Answer (score 2):

Simple googling reveals:

http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/code.php